# how to build ffmpeg with burn text on hls output while maintaining the aspect ratio

Tags: multithreading, ffmpeg, ubuntu-14.04, http-live-streaming, subtitle

My objective is to burn a text(watermark) at a particular time range on the outputed hls video, I also have to change just the height and maintain the aspect ratio which I am able to do but the burning in text part is not working. First the ffmpeg I used is for 14.04 ubuntu, details are [here](http://www.faqforge.com/linux/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu-14-04/). I don't think this build supports subtitle ([docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles)) filter which I could have used for my purpose as described [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo). when i enter ffmpeg into the terminal this is the output

```
(ffmpeg)aameer@falcon:~/Documents/projects/ffmpeg$ ffmpeg 
ffmpeg version N-78590-g5590ab4 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab
  libavutil      55. 18.100 / 55. 18.100
  libavcodec     57. 24.103 / 57. 24.103
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 32.100 /  6. 32.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
```

I tried

```
(ffmpeg)aameer@falcon:~/Documents/projects/ffmpeg$ ffmpeg -threads 4 -i "input_sintel_trailer_720p.mp4" -profile:v baseline -level 4.0 -vf scale="trunc(360*a/2)*2:360, subtitles='subtitles.srt'"  -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls videos/4444/index_4444_360_.m3u8
```

and got an error

```
[Parsed_subtitles_1 @ 0x2f1b7e0] Shaper: FriBidi 0.19.6 (SIMPLE) HarfBuzz-ng 0.9.27 (COMPLEX)
[Parsed_subtitles_1 @ 0x2f1b7e0] Unable to open subtitles.srt
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x2f1ac00] Error initializing filter 'subtitles' with args 'subtitles.srt'
Error opening filters!
```

then I tried this

```
(ffmpeg)aameer@falcon:~/Documents/projects/ffmpeg$ ffmpeg -threads 4 -i "input_sintel_trailer_720p.mp4" -profile:v baseline -level 4.0 -vf "scale='trunc(360*a/2)*2:360', drawtext:drawtext"  -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls videos/4444/index_4444_360_.m3u8
```

based on an answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/797117/ffmpeg-video-with-single-image-and-drawtext-failed-loop-causes-short-freeze) and got this error

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x2695c20] No such filter: 'drawtext:drawtext'
Error opening filters!
```

I tried a static build too which i got from [here](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/) but still couldn't make it work. with this static build i tried:

```
ffmpeg version N-63893-gc69defd Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 16 2014 05:38:01 with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-1)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit --extra-cflags='-I/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit/include -static' --extra-ldflags='-L/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit/lib -static' --extra-libs='-lxml2 -lexpat -lfreetype' --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-ffserver --disable-doc --enable-bzlib --enable-zlib --enable-postproc --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gray --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-libvpx
  libavutil      52. 89.100 / 52. 89.100
  libavcodec     55. 66.101 / 55. 66.101
  libavformat    55. 43.100 / 55. 43.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.101 / 55. 13.101
  libavfilter     4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'

(ffmpeg)aameer@falcon:~/Documents/projects/ffmpeg$ ./ffmpeg -threads 4 -i "input_sintel_trailer_720p.mp4" -profile:v baseline -level 4.0 -vf scale="trunc(360*a/2)*2:360, subtitles='subtitle.srt'"  -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls videos/4444/index_4444_360_.m3u8
```

but got an error

```
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): No such file or directory
```

Any help in this regard would be appreciated. I don't have much experience with compiling , otherwise would have done with support for libass as mentioned in the documentation [here](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles)

console output after trying the first potential answer:

```
(ffmpeg)aameer@falcon:~/Documents/projects/ffmpeg$ ls
bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal.mp4  ffmpeg_log_multiprocess.txt  ffmpeg.static.64bit.latest  input_sintel_trailer_720p.mp4  watermark.png
encoding_script.sh                    ffmpeg_log_simple.txt        ffprobe                     subtitle.srt
ffmpeg                                ffmpeg_log.txt               fontconfig                  videos
(ffmpeg)aameer@falcon:~/Documents/projects/ffmpeg$ ffmpeg -threads 4 -i input_sintel_trailer_720p.mp4 -profile:v baseline -level 4.0 -vf "scale=-2:360,subtitles='subtitle.srt'" -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls videos/4444/index_4444_360_.m3u8
ffmpeg version N-78590-g5590ab4 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab
  libavutil      55. 18.100 / 55. 18.100
  libavcodec     57. 24.103 / 57. 24.103
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 32.100 /  6. 32.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input_sintel_trailer_720p.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    title           : Sintel Trailer
    artist          : Durian Open Movie Team
    encoder         : Lavf52.62.0
    copyright       : (c) copyright Blender Foundation | durian.blender.org
    description     : Trailer for the Sintel open movie project
  Duration: 00:00:52.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1165 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 1033 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 126 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[Parsed_subtitles_1 @ 0x2bdb700] Shaper: FriBidi 0.19.6 (SIMPLE) HarfBuzz-ng 0.9.27 (COMPLEX)
[Parsed_subtitles_1 @ 0x2bdb700] Using font provider fontconfig
[libx264 @ 0x2bc8b60] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x2bc8b60] profile Constrained Baseline, level 4.0
Output #0, hls, to 'videos/4444/index_4444_360_.m3u8':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    description     : Trailer for the Sintel open movie project
    title           : Sintel Trailer
    artist          : Durian Open Movie Team
    copyright       : (c) copyright Blender Foundation | durian.blender.org
    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 640x360, q=-1--1, 24 fps, 24 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.24.103 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.24.103 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): No such file or directory
[aac @ 0x2bc9ac0] Qavg: -nan
(ffmpeg)aameer@falcon:~/Documents/projects/ffmpeg$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some guidance from @Mulvya and a Mortiz from ffmpeg group I was finally able to get the solution which I was looking for which I am pasting for anyone who is looking for something similar. The ffmpeg I was using was fine(you can get ffmpeg I used [here](http://www.faqforge.com/linux/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu-14-04/)), there is a new static build which also works you can get it [here](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) as was pointed out by mortiz but somehow small mistakes in the commands which I was using were the issue, command which worked for me :

```
ffmpeg -threads 4 -i input_sintel_trailer_720p.mp4 -profile:v baseline -level 4.0 -vf "scale=-2:360,subtitles=subtitle.ass:force_style='FontName=Aaargh/Aaargh.ttf,PrimaryColour=&HAA00FF00" -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls index_sub_ass_360_.m3u8
```

Note that I am using .ass subtitle file for some styling of the subtitles. For anyone searching for that , here is the .ass file with two different styles for two different subtitles:

```
[Script Info]
; Script generated by FFmpeg/Lavc57.24.103
ScriptType: v4.00+
PlayResX: 384
PlayResY: 288

[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: Default,Arial,16,&Hffffff,&Hffffff,&H0,&H0,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,1,0,5,10,10,10,0

[Events]
Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:10.00,0:00:10.04,Default,,0,0,0,,Senator, we're making\Nour final approach into Coruscant.
Dialogue: 0,0:00:30.00,0:00:30.05,Default,,0,0,0,,Very good, Lieutenant.
```

Moreover I am overriding the color and font and as mentioned by Mulvya that "scale=-2:360" part maintains the aspect ratio. Moreover I would like to reference some important links which helped me to reach to this point:

ffmpeg subtitle docs [here](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles-1)
.ass format description [here](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/)
ffmpeg with threads [here](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=715)
I also created a master list for different formats of hls videos if are interested in that look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/AboutHTTPLiveStreaming/about/about.html)
my discussion with mortiz [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org/msg08412.html)
for converting .srt to .ass subtitle file with ffmpeg check [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToConvertSubtitleToASS)
Hope this helps.

Comment: Good that this works, but it should work with SRT files, since that's the most common sub format, and it works successfully for many, including me..

Comment: I am sure it does Mulvya, but for some reason it didn't work for me and I am just sharing what worked for me.But your answer helped so that's why I up-voted it. Anyway thanks a lot for your help . Man I would have bought some cupcakes for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use the newer ffmpeg build #N-78590, which does have `libass` enabled as per the banner, to try these commands:

#### Using drawtext

```
ffmpeg -threads 4 -i "input_sintel_trailer_720p.mp4" \
-profile:v baseline -level 4.0 \
-vf "scale=-2:360,drawtext="fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:fontcolor=white:fontsize=30:text='Your Text':x=(W-tw)/2:y=H-th-30"" \
-start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls videos/4444/index_4444_360_.m3u8
```

#### Using subtitles

```
ffmpeg -threads 4 -i "input_sintel_trailer_720p.mp4" \
-profile:v baseline -level 4.0 \
-vf "scale=-2:360,subtitles='/path/to/subtitles.srt'" \
-start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls videos/4444/index_4444_360_.m3u8
```

Comment: can you please share some points regarding where and how do  I get this build(#N-78590)?

Comment: You already have it. It's the one you used for the first two commands.

Comment: gives me a syntax error: (ffmpeg)aameer@falcon:~/Documents/projects/ffmpeg$ ffmpeg -threads 4 -i "input_sintel_trailer_720p.mp4" -profile:v baseline -level 4.0 -vf "scale=-2:360,drawtext="fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:fontcolor=white:fontsize=30:text='Your Text':x=(W-tw)/2:y=H-th-30"" -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls videos/4444/index_4444_360_.m3u8
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: moreover scale=trunc(360*a/2)*2:360 is for the video to maintain aspect ratio

Comment: I'm on windows, so for linux, you'll have to experiment with single or double quotes, or else escape special characters.

Comment: `-2:360` will scale the width while maintaining aspect ratio and making the width an even number.

Comment: tried the second command too and it gives me this error with both the builds: [Parsed_subtitles_1 @ 0x2798da0] Unable to open subtitles.srt
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x2768960] Error initializing filter 'subtitles' with args 'subtitles.srt'
Error opening filters!

Comment: Is the srt file valid?

Comment: contents of the srt file : 1
00:00:10,440 --> 00:02:20,375
Senator, we're making
our final approach into Coruscant.

2
00:00:30,476 --> 00:00:40,501
Very good, Lieutenant.

Comment: how  do I check the validity of the srt file?

Comment: Download some other (known, working) SRT and compare for syntax.

Comment: corrected the link for .srt file and got this error: Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): No such file or directory

Comment: Paste the full console output in the Q.

Comment: had taken the srt sample from here https://matroska.org/technical/specs/subtitles/srt.html, i just changed the time to seconds as my video i am using is short

Comment: 1
00:00:10,440 --> 00:00:20,375
Senator, we're making
our final approach into Coruscant.

2
00:00:30,476 --> 00:00:40,501
Very good, Lieutenant.
this is the srt file content

Comment: Output to mp4 instead of HLS and check.

Comment: same error , tried without hls and also without threads but still the same error Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): No such file or directory

Comment: Check your output path and specify it absolutely. Make sure you have write permissions.

Comment: yes I do I am testing it locally and I am the admin. I am able to create the transcoded videos in different formats while maintaining the aspect ratio. The error appears after I try to burn the text on to the video either through drawtext or through subtitile.

Comment: after playing around was able to remove syntax error from the drawtext command : ffmpeg -threads 4 -i "input_sintel_trailer_720p.mp4" -profile:v baseline -level 4.0 -vf "scale=-2:360,drawtext='fontfile=Aaargh/Aaargh.ttf:fontcolor=white:fontsize=30:text='Your Text':x=(W-tw)/2:y=H-th-30" -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls videos/4444/index_4444_360_.m3u8
 but bumped into the same error : Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): No such file or directory

Comment: Ok, insert `-bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb` and output to HLS

Comment: where should I add that ?

Comment: As an output option, just before `-f hls`

Comment: command tried : ffmpeg -threads 4 -i "input_sintel_trailer_720p.mp4" -profile:v  baseline -level 4.0 -vf "scale=-2:360,drawtext=fontfile='Aaargh/Aaargh.ttf':fontcolor=white:fontsize=30:text='Your Text':x=(W-tw)/2:y=H-th-30" -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f hls videos/4444/index_4444_360_.m3u8  and error received: Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): No such file or directory

Comment: also tried  ffmpeg -threads 4 -i "input_sintel_trailer_720p.mp4" -profile:v baseline -level 4.0 -vf "scale=-2:360,drawtext=fontfile='Aaargh/Aaargh.ttf':fontcolor=white:fontsize=30:text='Your Text':x=(W-tw)/2:y=H-th-30" -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f hls videos/4444/index_4444_360_.m3u8 and got the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104392/discussion-between-aameer-and-mulvya).

Comment: Remove the font options i.e. fontfile, size, color. You don't have `--enable-libfontconfig`